# Running tensorflow code on a

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm totally a rookie to python and tensorflow, hope my description won't be too confusing. I run the tensorflow code (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10.py) following the tutorial (https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/deep_cnn), on a cloud system, which uses a hdfs file system (this may be useful), and there are some errors as shown below. It's totally OK when I run the code on my computer. I'd appreciate it if you guys can give me some advice.

```
Log Type: stdout
Log Upload Time: Tue Nov 21 10:16:29 +0800 2017
Log Length: 1692
Job name: default Task index: 0 CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES: [ 0 ]
usage: cifar10.py [-h] [--batch_size BATCH_SIZE] [--data_dir DATA_DIR]
                  [--use_fp16 USE_FP16] [--model_dir MODEL_DIR]
                  [--max_steps MAX_STEPS]
                  [--log_device_placement LOG_DEVICE_PLACEMENT]
                  [--log_frequency LOG_FREQUENCY]
cifar10.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --tf_fs hdfs://default --    tf_prefix /user/mt_tenant_120282045 --default_fs hdfs://gh-mos-    sigmoid01.gh.sankuai.com:8020 --worker_num 0 --num_gpus 1 --num_ps 0 --    num_worker 1
run failed:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tensorflow_main.py", line 282, in map_fun
  File "/usr/local/gpu/python/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 252, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, path_name)
  File "/usr/local/gpu/python/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 82, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_fname, mod_loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/local/gpu/python/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "cifar10.py", line 68, in <module>
    FLAGS = parser.parse_args()
  File "/usr/local/gpu/python/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 1704, in parse_args
    self.error(msg % ' '.join(argv))
  File "/usr/local/gpu/python/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 2374, in error
    self.exit(2, _('%s: error: %s\n') % (self.prog, message))
  File "/usr/local/gpu/python/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 2362, in exit
    _sys.exit(status)
SystemExit: 2

exit code is 2,failed.
tensorflow is executed completed!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tensorflow_main.py", line 291, in map_fun
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'mgr'
```

Comment: cifar10.py accepts one set of command-line arguments, such as `-h`, `--batch-size`, `--data-dir`, and `--use_fp16`. You're giving it a completely different set of arguments, including `--tf_fs`, `--tf_prefix`, and `--default_fs`. Also, that example isn't packaged for cloud execution. If you want to run a training job in the GCP, you need to use the gcloud command.

Comment: Thanks a lot, there is something wrong with the arguments.